# How to access Zend\db\Adapter inside Controller\Plugin\MyPlugins ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2

How am I able to access `Zend\db\Adapter` from within my controller plugin `Controller\Plugin\MyPlugins`?

I would like to execute

```
$this->getServiceLocator()
     ->getServiceLocator()
     ->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
     ->query("Select * from ABC ")
```

Answer (score 2):

From within the plugin you can access the controller (providing it extends `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin`), and therefore the service manager, using:

```
$this->getController()->getServiceLocator();
```

However accessing the service manager to fetch the plugin dependency (the adapter) from *within* the plugin is very bad practice.

A **much** better solution would be to 'inject' the adapter using a service factory.

```
use MyModule\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\MyPlugin;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class MyPluginFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $pluginManager)
    {
        $serviceManager = $pluginManager->getServiceLocator();

        return new MyPlugin(
            $serviceManager->get('My/Db/Adapter') // inject db adapter
        );
    }
}
```

Modify the plugin's `__construct` to allow the adapter in

```
class MyPlugin extends AbstractPlugin
{
    protected $dbAdapter;

    public function __construct(Adapter $dbAdapter)
    {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }
    //...
}
```

Lastly register it as a controller plugin in `Module.php` (or in `module.config.php`)

```
// Module.php
public function getControllerPluginConfig()
{
   return array(
     'factories' => array(
       'MyPlugin' => 'MyModule\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\MyPluginFactory'
     ),
   );
}
```

Comment: tried the below code inside the plugins 
    $this->getController()->getServiceLocator();  getting error as Fatal error: Call to a member function getServiceLocator() on a non-object 
I also tried to check for the $this->getController() but nothing appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code snippets

inside the controller path "modules/Admin/Controller/AreaController.php"

```
 public function arealistAction() {

    $Search = new Plugin\SearchBox();  //calling the searchbox class
    $Search->setButtons('Operator', 'query', 'Select id,name as text from Operator where Status=1 ');
    //passing parameter for searchbox
    $box = $Search->renderSearchBox();  

  }
```

The below code for SearchBox at "modules/Admin/Controller/Plugin/SearchBox.php"

```
namespace Admin\Controller\Plugin;

 class SearchBox extends \Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin {

  protected $RawSearch = array();

 //Get the user data 
  public function setButtons($label, $opt, $dbcols, $values = "") {
    $this->$RawSearch = array(
      'label' => $label,
      'opt' => $opt,
      'values' => $values,
      'dbcols' => $dbcols,
    );
  }

 //Process the search value 
  public function ProcessSearchValue($val) {

    switch ($val['opt']) {
      case 'date':
      case 'text':
        $vHtml = '<input type="text" name="' . $val['dbcols'] . '" id="' . $val['dbcols'] . '">';
        break;
      case 'query':
        $dbadpater = $this->getController()->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $Statement = $dbadpater->query($val['values']);
        $results = $Statement->execute();

        $vHtml = '<select name="' . $val['dbcols'] . '" id="' . $val['dbcols'] . '">';
        if (!empty($results)) {
          foreach ($results as $rkey => $rval) {
            $vHtml .='<option value="' . $rval['id'] . '">' . $rval['text'] . '</option>';
          }
        }
        $vHtml .='</select>';
        break;
    }
    return $vHtml;
  }


  public function ProcessOptValue($val) {
    $oHtml = '<select name="' . $val['dbcols'] . '" id="' . $val['dbcols'] . '">';
    $oHtml .='<option value="eq">Equal</option>';
    switch ($val['opt']) {
      case 'date':

        break;
      case 'text':
        $oHtml .='<option value="cnt">Contain</option>';
        $oHtml .='<option value="ncnt">Not Contain</option>';
        break;
      case 'query':
        $oHtml .='<option value="lth">Less Than</option>';
        $oHtml .='<option value="gth">Greater Than</option>';
        $oHtml .='<option value="leq">Less than Equal</option>';
        $oHtml .='<option value="geq">Greater than Equal</option>';
        break;
    }
    $oHtml .= '</select>';

    return $oHtml;
  }

  public function renderSearchBox() {
    if (!empty($this->RawSearch)) {
      $Sbox = '<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">';
      foreach ($this->RawSearch as $key => $val) {
        $Sbox.= '<tr>'
            . '<td><label>'.$val['label'].'</label></td>'
            . '<td>'.$this->ProcessOptValue($val).'</td>'
            . '<td>'.$this->ProcessSearchValue($val).'</td>'
            . '</tr>';
      }
      $Sbox.='</table>';
    }
    return $Sbox;
  }

 }
```

Now when i execute the statement  "$box = $Search->renderSearchBox();" it give me the error.
I am not able to execute the query inside the plugins.